# Inserting a custom Postgres datatype with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, insert, types

```
CREATE TYPE mpaa_rating AS ENUM (
    'G',
    'PG',
    'PG-13'
);

CREATE TABLE film (
    film_id integer DEFAULT nextval('film_film_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    rating mpaa_rating DEFAULT 'G'::mpaa_rating
);
```

I've tried the following:

1. `pg_insert($dbconn, "film", new array("rating" => "PG"));`
2. `pg_insert($dbconn, "film", new array("rating" => "'PG'::mpaa_rating"));`
3. `pg_insert($dbconn, "film", new array("rating" => "PG::mpaa_rating"));`

I get the error:
`unknown or system data type`

Comment: Good call on use of PG's enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pg_query($dbconn, "insert into film(rating) values('PG');");
```

`pg_insert` is experimental and has several shortcomings.

Comment: Or even better, use pg_query_params().